# Is there a way to get an average per day from my dataset in Python?

Tags: python, dataset, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with datetime and temperature that I get using a query to my database. I don't know how to get the average for each day. I want to create a list with x values for temperature and another array with the date associated with that value so I can plot the 2 to a chart.

Here is a small sample of what my dataset might look like when it is returned from the query:

```
[(21, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 57, 53)), 
(22, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 56, 52)), 
(26, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 55, 49)), 
(22, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 9, 54, 49)), 
(20, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 9, 53, 49)), 
(19, datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 9, 52, 48)), 
(18, datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 9, 51, 47)), 
(21, datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 9, 50, 46))]
```

I would like to end up with 2 lists that look like the below:

```
values = [23, 21, 19.3]
labels = ["2019-4-29", "2019-4-30", "2019-5-1"]
```

I'm not sure how to process my data so I end up with something like this and I'm not even sure the right terms to search for a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `pandas`, which you should, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    (21, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 57, 53)), 
    (22, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 56, 52)), 
    (26, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 9, 55, 49)), 
    (22, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 9, 54, 49)), 
    (20, datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 9, 53, 49)), 
    (19, datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 9, 52, 48)), 
    (18, datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 9, 51, 47)), 
    (21, datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 9, 50, 46)),
], columns=['value', 'date']).set_index('date')

# resample groups your values by 'd' which stands for "day" and aggregate them by average
df_day = df.resample('d').mean()
```

Here's the link to `pandas` documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! The only thing I had to change was `df_day = df.resample('d).mean()`

Answer (score 1):

Try `pandas` (`d` is your list):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Value', 'Date'])
df.groupby(df['Date'].map(datetime.datetime.date)).mean()
```

output:

```
                Value
Date                 
2019-04-29  23.000000
2019-04-30  21.000000
2019-05-01  19.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

The are two approaches:

1. Using `pandas`

Try to generate `TimeSeries`

```py
series = pd.DataFrame.from_values(data, columns=['Value', 'Date'], index=['Date'])
result = series.resample("D").mean()
```

output:

```py
                Value
Date                 
2019-04-29  23.000000
2019-04-30  21.000000
2019-05-01  19.333333
```

2. No `pandas` allowed

Use regular `dict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

grouper = defaultdict(list)
for value, date in data.items():
    grouper[date].append(value)

values = [sum(day) / len(day) for day in grouper.values()]
labels = list(grouper.keys())
```

The result will be as in example in question.